# Identify a single user in Apple's APN

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am looking through all docs about Apple's APN, but I guess I am not getting a simple question that I need answered quickly.  If I am setting up a Push Notification provider to interface with APNs, and I just want to send a message to John Doe, how do I get his Apple Device Id or token to send just to him?  Does my provider server application have to keep track of tokens and user names as my iPhone app is installed on different devices? Or is there a method or API for providers to query Apple to get this Device ID or token so that the message only goes to John? And if so, what do I use to ask Apple, does Apple know about "John Doe" as a user of my app?

I realize these answers are in the docs somewhere, but I need this specific questions answered quickly, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Brian

Answer (score 1):

> Does my provider server application have to keep track of tokens and user names as my iPhone app is installed on different devices.

Yes, it's your responsibility to receive the device token from each device where your app is installed, and to associate this data with whatever user information your app collects.